# link an app with an already created page?

Tags: facebook

I just created an app on facebook in order to publish the content of my website in a fan page, but I created the fan page before the app, now I don't know how to link my new app to my prev page; I just have the option of create a new page.

Comment: Did you create a Page Tab type application? You can call the add to page dialog to select the page you want to put it on - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/add_to_page/ 

Happy to give you more info about this if this is what you're looking for

Answer (score 2):

Hi Fran kinldy follow the below steps to link your apps with Fb page.

1. Fill canvas url and other details in the app settings.
2. Make the app to live & copy the app id and change the below URL.

www.facebook.com/add.php?api_key=your appid&pages=1

Then check your FB Page.Your apps will be linked.